# how was neighborhood distance was calculated for DBSCAN for temprature anomaly

Tags: dbscan

I was going through this below article and was wondering how to calculate neighborhood distance for dbscan with only temperature is available.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233919690_Anomaly_Detection_in_Temperature_Data_Using_DBSCAN_Algorithm